# iOS localization issue

Tags: swift, localization, native

Hi everyone I'm trying to add multilang to my app in native solution way. My problem is I did everything but still I can't read localized string from file.

[image: Firstly I add to my project Localize.string file.]
Firstly I add to my project Localize.string file.

[image: Secondly I add second language to Project/Base Code/]
Secondly I add second language to Project/Base Code/
[image: There is also my Localized.String file]
There is also my Localized.String file

There is my extension

```
extension String {

func localized() -> String {
    
    if let _ = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lang") {} else {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue("en", forKey: "lang")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
    
    let lang = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lang")
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
    let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
    
    return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
}}
```

I'm try to use label.text = "language".localized()

But my label output comes "language". I have cleaned Derived Data also. But I can't find solution

Comment: I think you need to set the file name as `Localizable.strings`

Comment: Thank you so much you were right issue was name of string file. If you answer the question from Answer Question (Blue button) I can vote it for your.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Change in function implementation

The easiest implementation for your `func localized() -> String` could be like

```
func localized() -> String {
    return Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: self, value: nil, table: "Localize") <-- the .strings file name from which you expect your localized value
}
```

If you have plan to have multiple `.strings` resource files, you may need to pass file name as the parameter to that function.

If you want to use single resource file with name `Localizable.strings`, use the following defination instead.

```
func localized() -> String {
    return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "") <-- Picks up localized version from `Localizable.strings`
}
```

You may avoid accessing `UserDefaults` and saving it calling `synchronize()` each time while derieving your localized value since it's a file I/O operation. Also I do not understand the usefulness of it.

#### 2. Pass Turkish as app language in launch options to see localization in action on simulator.

While running on silutor you may need to pass Turkish as app language from lanch options. Select your `Scheme` -> `Edit Scheme`
[image]

Comment: Jithin was solved my problem but also your solution was add some more usefulness, thanks also to you